# Como adicionar um evento ao balão de notificação do TrayIcon?

Tags: java, swing, ícone-de-bandeja

Eu tenho um aplicativo que utiliza a classe `TrayIcon` e estou exibindo uma mensagem através do método `displayMessage()`. (Um pequeno "balãozinho" que sobe do ícone representado pelo meu TrayIcon).

A chamada do método é a seguinte:

```
tray.displayMessage("My Title", "My Message", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
```

Onde `tray` é meu objeto do tipo `TrayIcon`.

Mas quando eu clico nesse "balãozinho" nada acontece. Na verdade, o "balãozinho" é fechado. Mas eu preciso fazer algo especifico quando essa mensagem é clicada.
Como eu adiciono um evento de mouse click nessa mensagem?

Se isso não for possível, alguém pode me sugerir alguma alternativa para resolver meu problema?

Segue um trecho do código:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;   
import java.awt.Image;    
import java.awt.SystemTray;  
import java.awt.Toolkit;  
import java.awt.TrayIcon;

public class Principal {

    Principal() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        Image trayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
        TrayIcon tray = new TrayIcon(trayImage, "Tray Icon Example");
        SystemTray sysTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        try {
            sysTray.add(tray);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tray.displayMessage("Atenção!", "Clique aqui para abrir mais detalhes.", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Principal();
    }

}
```

Comment: É aplicação desktop em swing?

Comment: Fernando, Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Com um exemplo de código fica mais fácil de te ajudar (dê uma olhada em [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help). De qualquer forma, você pode adicionar um `ActionListener` ou `MouseListener` ao [TrayIcon](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html), dito isso tenha ciência que isso não vai funcionar em todos os desktops / plataformas.

Comment: Sim, é uma aplicação desktop em swing.

Eu utilizo o seguinte para exibir essa mensage:

tray.displayMessage("My Title", "My Message", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
Obs.: "tray" é meu objeto TrayIcon.

Se eu adicionar um evento ao meu objeto do tipo TrayIcon, o evento funcionará para todo o objeto, mas a ideia não é bem essa.
O "balãozinho" aparece e some depois de alguns instantes. Ao clicar nessa mensagem ela some, mas eu preciso que ela execute uma devida ação (que eu já tenho desenvolvida). Mas não entendi como fazer isso.

Comment: Adicione um [mcve] de código na sua pergunta, para que seja possivel simular essa função de sua aplicaçao e te sugerir uma solução.

Comment: Editei a pergunta incluindo um exemplo, conforme solicitado.
Precisei pegar uma imagem da internet para tratar como "icon.png", não consegui encontrar um objeto Image padrão do Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicione um [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) no seu `TrayIcon`:

```
tray.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //ação que vai ocorrer quando o balão
               //for clicado
            }
        });
```

Veja implementado em um exemplo executável:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;   
import java.awt.Image;    
import java.awt.SystemTray;  
import java.awt.Toolkit;  
import java.awt.TrayIcon;

public class Principal {

    Principal() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        Image trayImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getResource("icon.png"));
        TrayIcon tray = new TrayIcon(trayImage, "Tray Icon Example");
        SystemTray sysTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        tray.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "clicou");
            }
        });
        try {
            sysTray.add(tray);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tray.displayMessage("Atenção!", "Clique aqui para abrir mais detalhes.", TrayIcon.MessageType.WARNING);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Principal();
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]